# how to set a value of node in defaultTreeNode

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.0 M2, and I use DefaultTreeNode, with the component p:tree and it works fine.
My problem is that I want the value of node selected were be different from the the value of node displayed.
Need your help please!

Comment: I don't really understand. What do you mean by `I want the value of node selected were be different from the the value of node displayed`? You have an ajax tree and you want the value of the node expanded? Explain more and show some code/pseudo-cod of what you have and what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

You may display any text you like for each node. For example, this is a bit changed example from primefaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/treeSelectionSingle.jsf) (TreeBeen.java is the same):

```
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
    <p:tree id="treeSingle" value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node"
        selectionMode="single" selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}">
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="Node" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>

    <p:commandButton value="Display Selected" update="growl"
        actionListener="#{treeBean.displaySelectedSingle}" />
</h:form>
```

"Node" text is displayed for each node, but it's data value is displayed on button click event.

Comment: my tree looks like this: option1,option2,option3 , I want when I check option1 the value selected would be for example "op1"

Comment: One of the constructors is `DefaultTreeNode(Object data, TreeNode parent)`, so you set node data, not only string. Try get label from this data. Or you can extend existing DefaultTreeNode and provide label field for each node.